# Pyglet text_input example adaptation "Can only assign sequence of same size" on key press

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyglet

I am trying to create a simple 'widget' to accept keyboard entries for use in calculations. However, whenever an entry box is selected and a key is pressed, I receive an error. I am following the pyglet example ['text_input.py'](https://github.com/adamlwgriffiths/Pyglet/blob/master/examples/text_input.py) almost exactly and thus I am unsure of where the error is originating from. Any help on fixing this error would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Code:

```
import pyglet

class rectangle2D():
    def __init__(self, batch, ul, lr, color):
        self.vertices = batch.add(4, pyglet.gl.GL_QUADS, None,
        ('v2f', (ul[0],lr[1], ul[0],ul[1], lr[0],ul[1], lr[0],lr[1])),
        ('c3B', (color[0],color[1],color[2], color[0],color[1],color[2], color[0],color[1],color[2], color[0],color[1],color[2])))

#class text():
#   def __init__(self, batch, )

class entry():
    def __init__(self, batch, pos, text, clFG, clBG, width, padx, pady):
        self.document = pyglet.text.document.UnformattedDocument(text)
        self.document.set_style(0, len(self.document.text), dict(color = clFG))
        self.font = self.document.get_font()
        self.height = self.font.ascent - self.font.descent

        self.layout = pyglet.text.layout.IncrementalTextLayout(self.document, width, self.height, multiline = False, batch = batch)
        self.caret = pyglet.text.caret.Caret(self.layout)

        self.layout.x = pos[0]
        self.layout.y = pos[1]

        self.container = rectangle2D(batch, (pos[0]-padx, pos[1]-pady), (pos[0]+width+padx, pos[1]+self.height+pady), clBG)

    def hit(self, x, y):
        return ((0 < x - self.layout.x < self.layout.width) and (0 < y - self.layout.y < self.layout.height))



class Application(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Application, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        #Colors
        self.clBG = (36, 36, 36)
        self.clButton = (179, 15, 6)
        self.clPanel = (20, 20, 20)
        self.clEntry = (255, 255, 255)
        self.clEntryText = (0, 0, 0)
        self.clText = (255, 255, 255)

        #Fonts
        self.fontHelvetica = pyglet.font.load('Helvetica')

        #2D object creation
        self.batch = pyglet.graphics.Batch()

        #Background
        self.background = rectangle2D(self.batch, (0,self.height), (self.width, 0), self.clBG)

        #Text entries
        self.entries = [
            entry(self.batch, (25, 200), '', self.clEntryText, self.clEntry, 200, 3, 3),
            entry(self.batch, (25, 400), '', self.clEntryText, self.clEntry, 200, 3, 3),
            entry(self.batch, (25, 600), '', self.clEntryText, self.clEntry, 200, 3, 3)
        ]
        self.text_cursor = self.get_system_mouse_cursor('text')

        self.focus = None
        self.set_focus(self.entries[0])

        #Rendering
        pyglet.clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 0.05)

    def update(self, dt):
        self.clear()
        self.batch.draw()

    def on_resize(self, width, height):
        super(Application, self).on_resize(width, height)
        self.background.ul = (0,height)
        self.background.lr = (width, 0)

    def on_mouse_motion(self, x, y, dx, dy):
        for entry in self.entries:
            if entry.hit(x, y):
                self.set_mouse_cursor(self.text_cursor)
                break
        else:
            self.set_mouse_cursor(None)

    def on_mouse_press(self, x, y, button, modifiers):
        for entry in self.entries:
            if entry.hit(x, y):
                self.set_focus(entry)
                break
        else:
            self.set_focus(None)

        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.on_mouse_press(x, y, button, modifiers)

    def on_mouse_drag(self, x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers):
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.on_mouse_drag(x, y, dx, dy, buttons, modifiers)

    def on_text(self, text):
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.on_text(text)

    def on_text_motion(self, motion):
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.on_text_motion(motion)

    def on_text_motion_select(self, motion):
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.on_text_motion_select(motion)

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == pyglet.window.key.TAB:
            if modifiers & pyglet.window.key.MOD_SHIFT:
                dir = -1
            else:
                dir = 1

            if self.focus in self.entries:
                i = self.entries.index(self.focus)
            else:
                i=0
                dir = 0

            self.set_focus(self.entries[(i+dir) % len(self.entries)])

        elif symbol == pyglet.window.key.ESCAPE:
            pyglet.app.exit()

    def set_focus(self, focus):
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.visible = False
            self.focus.caret.mark = self.focus.caret.position = 0

        self.focus = focus
        if self.focus:
            self.focus.caret.visible = True
            self.focus.caret.mark = 0
            self.focus.caret.position = len(self.focus.document.text)

window = Application(1280, 720, caption = "Test Application")
pyglet.app.run()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_ctypes/callbacks.c", line 234, in 'calling callback function'
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 641, in f
    result = event_handler(msg, wParam, lParam)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\win32\__init__.py", line 732, in _event_char
    self.dispatch_event('on_text', text)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\window\__init__.py", line 1312, in dispatch_event
    if EventDispatcher.dispatch_event(self, *args) != False:
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 407, in dispatch_event
    if getattr(self, event_type)(*args):
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Downloads\Project\PygletDesignCalculator.py", line 104, in on_text
    self.focus.caret.on_text(text)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\caret.py", line 433, in on_text
    self._layout.document.insert_text(pos, text, self._next_attributes)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\document.py", line 431, in insert_text
    self.dispatch_event('on_insert_text', start, text)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\event.py", line 400, in dispatch_event
    if handler(*args):
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 1878, in on_insert_text
    self._update()
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 1939, in _update
    self._update_vertex_lists()
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 2143, in _update_vertex_lists
    line.boxes, context)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 1467, in _create_vertex_lists
    box.place(self, i, x, y, context)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\text\layout.py", line 373, in place
    ('c4B/dynamic', colors))
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\__init__.py", line 373, in add
    vlist._set_attribute_data(i, array)
  File "C:\Users\Tatsumi\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pyglet\graphics\vertexdomain.py", line 453, in _set_attribute_data
    region.array[:] = data
ValueError: Can only assign sequence of same size
```

Comment: It is surprising that this questions still has no answers!

Comment: @Is_this_my_username Just ran across this problem in Pyglet. My error was that I was trying to assign a three color tuple `color=(255, 255, 255)` to one that required four colors `color=(255, 255, 255, 255)`. OP has a lot of colors going on here.